# Overriding SCons Cache Copy Function

Tags: python, caching, scons, build-system, hardlink

I'm trying to figure out how to override the behaviour when SCons copies artifacts from the cache directory (given by CacheDir) to used hard-links.

My current try

```
def link_or_copy_file(class_instance, src, dst):
    # do hardlinking instead...

SCons.Defaults.DefaultEnvironment()._copy_from_cache = link_or_copy_file
SCons.Defaults.DefaultEnvironment()._copy2_from_cache = link_or_copy_file

env = Environment()

env._copy_from_cache = link_or_copy_file
env._copy2_from_cache = link_or_copy_file
```

has no effect on subsequent usage of `env`. The function `link_or_copy_file` is never called. What is wrong?

Isn't it possible to override a Python class member function in this way.

*Update*: Also note that I'm doing this after `env.Decider()` has been called as this function possibly overrides the members `_copy_from_cache` and `_copy2_from_cache`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally figured out that

```
import SCons.Environment
SCons.Environment.Environment._copy_from_cache = link_or_copy_file
SCons.Environment.Environment._copy2_from_cache = link_or_copy_file
```

worked.