# Does scons cache supports hard links?

Tags: scons

I use scons cache functionality (--cache=nolinked --cache-dir=<path> options).

I want it to create hard links from the cache to the build tree. Is that supported by scons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently.

You can see the code here:
https://github.com/SCons/scons/blob/master/src/engine/SCons/CacheDir.py#L80

Is your cachedir on the same filesystem as your build area? If not, then hardlinks won't work.

What's the goal here? Reduced disk usage? Or something else?

Comment: My cachedir is on the same filesystem.

Comment: The goal is twofold:
1. reduce disk usage
2. reduce time spent on file copying

Comment: Gotcha.  So you'd expect some flag to set hard-soft-copy something like that? (Similar to what we have for variant dir duplicate logic)

Comment: Not sure I fully understand your question but yes it would be nice to have some switch to enable hard links instead of plain copy.

Comment: I have also found this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27866811/overriding-scons-cache-copy-function which looks interesting

Comment: Please file an issue on SCons's github issue tracker requesting support for hardlinking when copying files into cachedir.

Comment: Thanks! I do see real value in it, but It might take a bit to get to it. Of course Pull Requests are welcome, though this likely wouldn't be an easy place to start SCons development.